# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом и при двух подлежащих?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Андрей дождался, пока Игорь подойдёт поближе(,) и спросил:

— Как дела?

Comment: Это лишь пример, который был придуман за несколько секунд для демонстрации конструкции)) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение: ‟Пока Игорь подойдет поближе” — является временным придаточным, которое обособляется запятыми.